# Simple parsing question

Tags: c++, c, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) (C++ FAQ entry)

In C and C++ how is the expression `x+++++y` parsed? As `x++ ++ +y` or as `x++ + ++y` ?

Comment: You're not considering actually writing it, though, right? *Right?* ;-)

Comment: Entering an obfuscated code competition?

Comment: @Lucero : This question has no relation with the one that you have added in your comment.

Comment: @Lucero:  No, that question is about what happens after tokenization, and this is about tokenization.

Comment: @Lucero: Echoing David, this question is about tokenization and parsing (hence the `parsing` tag). The questions you're finding are about sequence points, which are a totally different thing. (The difference being that `i = i++ + ++i` involves the same variable more than once, introducing sequence point stuff, whereas this question talks about independent variables.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x+++++y` is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y` and not as `x ++ + ++ y`. According to [Maximal Munch principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) "*the tokenizer should keep reading characters from the source file until adding one more character causes the current token to stop making sense*"

`x++ ++ +y` should not compile(In C and C++) because the post-increment operator `++` requires an `lvalue` as an argument and returns an `rvalue`.

Comment: This is true for all languages which use greedy/longest-match regexes for tokenization - which should be most of them (actually, I can't think of one that doesn't).

Comment: *"`x++ ++ +y` should not compile"* And indeed, it doesn't (on `gcc` anyway): `error: lvalue required as increment operand` Wow was I relieved to see that.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all forms of '+++++++++' are uncompilable.  MSVC at least happily accepts some of them and then does WTF knows what with it.  There's this little, in-house utility of ours that has always been given to an intern to do (not my decision).  It's got shit like that in it all over the place.

Comment: `x++ ++ +y` will compile if `x` or `y` is of a class type with suitably defined operator overloads.

Comment: A bit of trivia: the next version of C++ will relax the "maximal munch" rule for ">>" tokens when dealing with template parameters.

Comment: "According to Maximal Munch principle" -- the world is not composed of only LL grammars, is it?